# How to fix ImportError with 'EventGridPublisherClient' in Azure HTTPTrigger function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

Can anyone help me with the following error:

> Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'EventGridPublisherClient' from 'azure.eventgrid'

This is the code for the HTTPTrigger:

```
import os
import logging
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.eventgrid import EventGridPublisherClient, EventGridEvent
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # Parse request body
    #req_body = req.get_json()

    # Get Event Grid topic endpoint and key from environment variables
    topic_endpoint = os.environ.get('EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_ENDPOINT')
    topic_key = os.environ.get('EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_KEY')
    

    # Create Event Grid publisher client
    credential = AzureKeyCredential(topic_key)
    client = EventGridPublisherClient(topic_endpoint, credential)

    # Create an event
    event = EventGridEvent(
        event_type="MyCustomEventType",
        subject="MyCustomSubject",
        data={
            "message": "Hello, Event Grid!"
        },
        data_version="1.0"
    )

    # Publish the event
    client.send(event)

    # Return a response
    return func.HttpResponse("Event published to Event Grid topic.", status_code=200)
```

The requirements.txt looks like this:

```
urllib3
uplink
requests
azure-functions
azure
azure-eventgrid
azure-core
```

Running locally works fine but when I deploy to Azure I get the error above. I'm going in circles and don't seem to find any useful information to help with this. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Any reason why you are trying to use the SDK? Why not use the Azure function Eventgrid output binding? It was made precisely for this purpose. Then you don't even need to include the libraries in your requirements. It's all included in the Azure functions extensions bundle.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-output?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv3

Comment: Yes, the output binding wasn't working for me either, authentication issue raised in a separate question on this forum. For now, I just need to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to Deploy Azure Function HTTP Trigger with the below code and it was successful.

**Code:**

```py
import os
import logging
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.eventgrid import EventGridPublisherClient, EventGridEvent
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    topic_endpoint = os.environ.get('EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_ENDPOINT')
    topic_key = os.environ.get('EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_KEY')
    
    credential = AzureKeyCredential(topic_key)
    client = EventGridPublisherClient(topic_endpoint, credential)

    event = EventGridEvent(
        event_type="MyCustomEventType",
        subject="MyCustomSubject",
        data={
            "message": "Hello, Event Grid!"
        },
        data_version="1.0"
    )

    client.send(event)
    return func.HttpResponse("Event published to Event Grid topic.", status_code=200)
```

**local.setting.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<your-storage-account-connection-string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_KEY": "<your-event-grid-topic-key>",
    "EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_ENDPOINT": "<your-event-grid-topic-endpoint>"
  }
}
```

**requirement.txt:**

```json
azure-functions
azure-eventgrid==4.0.0
azure-core>=1.18.0
```

I added **EVENT_GRID_TOPIC_ENDPOINT** and **eventgridtopickey** in **Application.settings** in **Configuration** functionapp at azure portal,

[image]

I **run** the above code and got below results:

[image]

With the above **URL**, I can able to see output at browser as below,

[image]

Then, I **deployed** above code to **functionapp** as below,

[image]

Select the **functionapp** that you want to deploy,

[image]

Click on **Delpoy** option,

[image]

The HTTP trigger function **deployed successfully**,
Click on **View output**,

[image]

The output shows that the **HTTP trigger** function is successfully **deployed** to **functionapp** as below,

[image]

**Successfully deployed** to **functionapp** in **Azure portal** as below,

[image]

Comment: You made some minor changes to what I had, I copied and it works for me now as well, thanks!